# Preloading Images to prevent Repainting in Chrome Rendering on Windows PC

Tags: performance, google-chrome, parallax, smooth-scrolling, requestanimationframe

I have a website with 3 full screen background images that use a custom parallax scrolling script utilizing **requestAnimationFrame** and **transform:translate3d()** for its animation. I did this because after a fair amount of research on the subject of visual performance this was the best alternative then using canvas.

My problem is that my page runs very smooth on Firefox 29.1 (*because it is most definitely using the computers GPU to render the page and composite layers) however for some reason, Chrome is has some major bottlenecks.

I am getting tremendous performance spikes (way less then 30fps) when I scroll down my page... but an interesting thing I noticed was that it happens specifically just as one of the background images that is being animated with the script (set as background-position:cover) enters into the viewport.

There is a repaint operation happening because the background image is being resized to fit the viewport width/height and that is causing a tremendous performance hit. Considering that the gpu isnt working correctly for my Chrome, but also that I would like to make my page perform super silky smooth when scrolling even without hardware acceleration, is there a method of preloading images/frames and having them already resized before they are scrolled onto screen? Like a frame buffering technique to ensure all the calculations and resizing is finished well before a user scrolls to that image on screen?